# MacBook Pro dual-boot Windows using Boot Camp - Performance loss?

Tags: windows, macos, multi-boot, boot-camp

Long story short: I need a Mac for programming, girlfriend needs Windows for every day tasks (movies, web browsing, ocasional Win Games). 
I didn't specify the version of either OSX / Win because they will be the latest available (assuming Yosemite and Win10). I'm aiming for a 15", no Retina MacBook Pro.
I have 2 concerns:

- **1 - the overheating when running Win over Boot Camp**. Should I be worried? is there a viable solution for the overheating? Like laptop cooling pads?
- **2 - performance loss/freezes/crashes when running Win over Boot Camp**. Say, this isn't so important. But I don't know what to expect - will it behave like a "regular" Win PC? I'm expecting it to be better than running Win in a virtual machine, but how much better is it going to be?

Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The overheating problem is common in MBA and MBP running Windows!!! This is due to poor fan speed management... To solve it, use Macs Fan Control by CRYSTALIDEA... It'll solve the heating problem in an instant!!!
2. There won't be any performance loss or crashes if you run Windows natively... In fact, Windows 8.1 and 10 run better and faster on my MacBook Pro and iMac than they do on HP Envy or Dell Inspiron... It feels cleaner and stable! (All Core i5 processors)

Note: Running Windows under VM will frustrate you! Common freezes if your RAM is 4 gigs or lower and using shortcuts is hell...
Plus there is performance issue and forget about gaming!!!
The experience is way better when you run it natively!